# How to check if ObjectResult<> contains a value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

How do I check to see if the ObjectResult<> has a value or not? Right now it's returning values but will it throw an exception is there is nothing to return?

This is the section of code that I need to check so I do not have to depend on a try catch block

---

```
iProjInfo.ProjectLeafs = db.proc_GetProjectLeafs(projectID).ToList<IProjectLeafs>();
```

---

```
public static Task<IProjectInfo> GetProjectInfo(int projectID)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
      {
          using (var db = new StorefrontSystemEntities())
          {
              IProjectInfo iProjInfo = db.proc_GetProject_ForDrawings(projectID).Single<IProjectInfo>();

              try
              {
                  iProjInfo.ProjectLeafs = db.proc_GetProjectLeafs(projectID).ToList<IProjectLeafs>();
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {

              }
              return iProjInfo;
          };
      });
}
```

Comment: Most likely you'll get an empty list. Then you can just do .Count() condition to check if there is anything in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the stored procedure is getting executed and returning a result set; even if it is empty (no records returned by the stored procedure), you can be sure of an empty list being returned.